# Convert RDD[Array[Row]] to RDD[Row]

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

How to convert RDD[Array[Row]] to RDD[Row]?

Details:

I have some use case where my parsing function returns type Array[Row] for some data and Row for some data. How will I convert both of these to RDD[Row] for further use?

CODE SAMPLE

```
private def getRows(rdd: RDD[String], parser: Parser): RDD[Row] = {

var processedLines = rdd.map { line =>      
  map(p => parser.processBeacon(line) }

val rddOfRowsList = processedLines.map { x =>
  x match {
    case Right(obj) => obj.map { p =>          
      MyRow.getValue(p)
    }//I can use flatmap here
    case Left(obj) =>          
      MyRow.getValue(obj)
  }//Cant use flatmap here
}

 // Here I have to convert rddOfRowsList to RDD[Row]
 //?????
 val rowsRdd =?????
 //


rowsRdd
```

}

```
    def processLine(logMap: Map[String, String]):Either[Map[String, Object], Array[Map[String, Object]]] =  
         {
           //process
         }
```

Comment: Can you add some code of what you are doing as well as some example input & wanted output?

Comment: Similar question I met. Answer here https://stackoverflow.com/q/55702513/6766464

Answer (score 0):

Use `flatMap`;

```
rdd.flatMap(identity)
```

Comment: In the 2nd case where I get one row , flatmap will not work

Answer (score 0):

You ca use flatmap to get new rdd, and then use union to compose them.

Answer (score 0):

use flatMap to flattern the contents of RDD

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.